# Показ текста, при нажатии на кнопку GTK+, c

Tags: c, gtk3

Как при нажатии на кнопку показать текст на той же форме, где и кнопка?

так не работает

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget *window = NULL;
GtkWidget *v_box = NULL;

void
show_text(void)
{
    GtkWidget *label = NULL;

    label = gtk_label_new("hello, some");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(v_box), label, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    return;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *button = NULL;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 500, 500);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Something");

    v_box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);

    button = gtk_button_new();
    gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(button), "show");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(v_box), button, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(show_text), NULL);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), v_box);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

```
gtk_widget_show(label); // решение
```